# map {lc} does not work for an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a file with word list, each on new line and in capital letters, like

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC
- etc.

Now, what's wrong with the code which was supposed to convert the array to lowercase but fails: mapped array is uppercase again?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(MYFILE, "$ARGV[0]") || die "opening bigList $!";
@Llist=<MYFILE>;
close (MYFILE);

@lc_word = map { lc } @Llist;
print @lc_word;
```

Comment: Exactly how does it not work?

Comment: There is no need to (ever) explicitly open $ARGV[ 0 ].  The script above can be re-written: '@lc_word = map{ lc } <>; print @lc_word'

Comment: @William Pursell Sometimes there are reasons to open `$ARGV[0]` explicitly.

Comment: @mob I may have overstated with the "ever"...but it is very rarely necessary to do so, and in a case like this definitely not needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works for me.

I re-wrote the code following the accepted best practices, just so you're not stuck using old-style Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $in, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die "cannot open '$ARGV[0]': $!";

my @Llist=<$in>;
close ($in);

my @lc_word = map { lc } @Llist;
print @lc_word
```

Additional notes: what's the encoding of the file? If it is pure ASCII, then this will work, otherwise you will need to specify the encoding in the `open`, for example for a utf8 file:  `open( my $in, '<:utf8', $ARGV[0])`. Also, slurping the whole file in memory with `my @Llist=<$in>;` is somewhat frowned upon, although in you case you will have the whole lowercased list in memory anyway.

If what you want is to lowercase the initial array (Llist), then you need to replace the `map` with `foreach my $word(@Llist) { $word= lc $word; }`

Comment: a simpler one-liner: `perl -pe'$_=lc'`, no need for a map here. I assume what the OP's asks is part of a bigger piece of code though.

Comment: Actually it's utf8, so I might need to specify encoding, indeed.

Comment: if you want to output to be in utf8, then you also have to specify it by writing `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`

Comment: best practice typically includes not explicitly opening $ARGV[0], but just reading from ARGV using <> with no file-handle.

Comment: @William Pursell you're right. I tried to limit the rewrite a bit, so I focused on the most important here, using a lexical filehandle and the 3 arg form of `open`.

Comment: Thanks.Changing code this way now it works, also adding the line `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';` and substituting `my $in, '<:utf8',`